# Yahoo Mobil view word-break getting removed/stripped

Tags: html, email, templates, yahoo-mail

I am creating email template.In Yahoo mobile view, css **word-break** is getting removed/stripped while rendering. It is removed from inline-css as well as from head section. Any solution for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.no-wrdbrk{
word-break:keep-all;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="word-break:keep-all;" class="no-wrdbrk">
Several new studies have found that yoga may lower depression and emotional eating, if done on a consistent basis. At the 125th Annual Convention of the American Psychological Association, four separate studies were presented that pointed to similar positive findings about the benefits of yoga.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try `word-break:normal;` like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.no-wrdbrk{
word-break:normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="word-break:normal;" class="no-wrdbrk">
Several new studies have found that yoga may lower depression and emotional eating, if done on a consistent basis. At the 125th Annual Convention of the American Psychological Association, four separate studies were presented that pointed to similar positive findings about the benefits of yoga.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

There are

> CSS Syntax:
>
> word-break: normal|break-all|keep-all|initial|inherit;

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This is not working. 'word-break' style is stripped off in Yahoo mobile view

Comment: That is the web version of Yahoo mail right? Is it working on the Yahoo mail app?

Comment: The issue is in web in mobile not in app. This need to be fixed in web not app

Comment: The Yahoo mail site renders HTML different. Try the style tag in the body with important tag (without space).

Answer (score 0):

```css
word-break:inherit !important;
```

worked for me